# ImageView scaletype does't work in code with api 28

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, scaletype

I have code working good with api lower 28 :

```
val im = view?.findViewById(R.id.imageView) as ImageView
val lp_im: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = im.layoutParams 
lp_im.height = height
im.setImageResource(rightAnswer!!.id)
im.requestLayout()
```

xml:

```
       <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView

            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"


            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"


            android:padding="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cv1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cv1"


            app:riv_corner_radius_bottom_left="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
            app:riv_corner_radius_bottom_right="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
            app:riv_corner_radius_top_left="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
            app:riv_corner_radius_top_right="@dimen/card_corner_radius" />
```

But on api28  devices scale doesn't work and I got something like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh2zk.jpg)
Does anybody know the reason?

Comment: dont use broken `RoundedImageView`, just for testing, use normal `ImageView` and you will see that everything is working - and  if you want rounded corners use `RoundedBitmapDrawable` instead

Comment: Thank you, it works. But unfortunately, RoundedBitmapDrawable  daoesn't work with scale (centercrope)

Comment: so, you have to fix `RoundedImageView` ;-(